# Static logger for cross-plattform, e.g. Java (Applet) and Android

Tags: java, android, logging, cross-platform, applet

I want to use somthing like:

```
MyLogger.e("MyApp","I have an error.");
```

in a cross-plattform project, where MyLogger should be static to make it available in the whole project.

So I was trying something like:

```
MyAndroidLogger implements MyLogger {
   public static void e(String strApp, String strErr) {
     Log.e(strApp, strErr);
}

MyAppletLogger implements MyLogger {
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger();
   public static void e(String strApp, String strErr) {
     logger.e(strApp, strErr);
}
```

The compiler complains about the static. How do I do this? Is it possible at all? If not, what's the right approach?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This might actually be the solution: http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-factory.

Comment: Or this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-abstract-factory.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a interface the way you are trying to. You have to call either

```
MyAndroidLogger.e("MyApp","I have an error.");
```

or

```
MyAppletLogger.e("MyApp","I have an error.");
```

If you want to use same call on both platforms you have to create a helper class that has a reference to the correct class:

```
MyLoggerHelper.e("MyApp","I have an error.");
```

where the MyLoggerHelper is a class that knows which one of the first two calls it should call and forwards this call to appropriate one.

Comment: Okay. I just tried this. It works. I gave it an up-vote. Let me however try the other provided solution(s), before I choose "the right answer". But...,thank very much! :-)

Comment: Go for the singleton answer provided by OscarRyz. That's the best practice in this.

Comment: Okay, I heard you. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I tried this and (I thought) I had it running. But I don't like the dependencies that come with this approach. The "helper"-class is always needed and it won't compile without the source for the applet AND android. So each project has to run with the other platforms sources. (The singleton answer by "OscarRyz" I could also not implement so far; see comment there) :-/

Comment: You can use reflection in the helper class to get rid of the dependencies. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces don't have static methods. That's why you can't invoke them.

You may try using a singleton.

```
YourWhateverLogger.getInstance().e("Hello");
```

Comment: Okay. I keep on trying to find a solution, that includes the singleton pattern and would make the above call possible. But I don't really see how that would work. I just had to find out that a Singleton as a base class is (almost) impossible and not recommended. The only thing left that I can imagine is the solution provided by Juhani, and make the "Helper"-class a singleton. If that is not what is meant here, I'd be happy to get a little more detail. Thanks.